# How can I convert a user-friendly date format to mm/dd/yy?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a date in the format [day-of-week], [month abbrev.] [date of month] to a more common format, `mm/dd/yy`. `yy` will always be the current year.

For example, Tue, Apr 17 would become 04/17/18.

My first thought was to create an array containing the abbreviated month names, and then looping that array to return the month in `mm` format. But is that overkill? What would be the most efficient way to handle this conversion?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the input date, or how to format the result?

Comment: This library will be helpful - http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: You can use the moment.js library for both.

Comment: Use objects instead. `const months = {"Jan": "01", "Feb": "02", `…`};`. Then, if `month` is `"Apr"`, just use `months[month]` to get `"04"`.

Comment: Most people use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) to handle date parsing and formatting.

Comment: This might help-    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript